# Stripe error Refunds

Tags: banking

I inadvertently refunded all my car club's annual membership fees in my Stripe account, currently showing as "succeeded" in the refunded column
That was  4 days ago. Nothing has happened yet
What, if anything, is the best way to unwind this in UK?

Answer (score 4):

There usually isn't a way to "un-refund a refund".  You could talk to each affected member and sweet-talk them into paying again.

Everyone will know about it anyway, so no point covering it up.  Talk to your governing board and say "oops".  The governing board needs to agree how to treat this:

- simply waive those membership dues and let them remain members for the year anyway, since it's the club's error
- allow them to *retain* membership with full accrued benefits if they re-pay the dues within 90 days
- or whatever.  Feel free to recommend something to the Board.

Then, the Board needs to review the by-laws, and make advance rulings how the gap will affect everything the by-laws talk about in terms of member rights.  For instance some say you must pay by date X or you're not a member.  They might also say you must be a member for Y years to run for the Board.  Stuff like that needs to be addressed in advance by the Board, so somebody doesn't raise a fuss later and try to take advantage of the situation.

Then you need to send them a letter describing the "oops".  Once you confirm that the refunds did indeed go through, then execute what the Board says to do -- waive their membership fee for the year, or dun them to re-pay their membership dues within X days to remain members, etc.

Comment: that was a GREAT (and thorough) answer!